# Which datatype is good for this format (2008-02-04T10:20:00.000+00:00) in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, api

I'm calling an online API and i stored API response in mysql db.
API response:

```
{
        "id": 4988,
        "arrived_at": "2007-05-02T09:07:24.000+01:00",
        "cancelled_at": null,
        "completed_at": "2007-05-02T09:56:28.000+01:00",
        "confirmed_at": null,
        "did_not_attend_at": null,
        "duration": 15,
        "finish_time": "2007-05-02T09:50:00.000+01:00",
        "in_surgery_at": "2007-05-02T09:38:06.000+01:00",
        "metadata": {},
        "notes": "Examination",
        "patient_name": "Michael Abbott",
        "patient_id": 2,
        "patient_image_url": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e47cc318b9c836005f019d3ca1bfe670.jpg?&r=pg&d=identicon&s=190",
        "payment_plan_id": 1,
        "pending_at": null,
        "practitioner_id": 1,
        "reason": "Exam",
        "start_time": "2007-05-02T09:35:00.000+01:00",
        "state": "Completed",
        "treatment_description": null,
        "user_id": 14692,
        "created_at": "2019-06-10T19:25:26.326+01:00",
        "updated_at": "2019-06-10T19:25:26.326+01:00"
    }
```

This API gives me this response with this 2008-02-04T10:20:00.000+00:00 format.
Which datatype is good for this date format ?

Comment: This value as-is can be stored in the column of any string type only. VARCHAR(255) is preferred.

Comment: Just convert it and store it as a standard date type

Comment: If i get any problem with getting records on behave of this date ?

Comment: @Strawberry The timezone information will be lost in DATETIME and may be altered in TIMESTAMP. If timezone must be saved then separate column for it needed.

Comment: And store the time zone bit in a separate column, if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a datetime(3) type, except that that won't store the offset.

If the offset is ever non-0, I would store the time in utc and the offset in a separate column, e.g original_offset.